# Do women tend to use the word "lovely" more often than men?

Tags: word-usage, political-correctness

Do women tend to use the word ***lovely*** more often than men do?

And also, should men rather avoid using this word when describing something they liked?

*Meta*: I hope this question doesn't sound too sexist (though to an extent it is, of course).

Comment: I don't have a reference, but I hear British men saying it far more often than American men.

Comment: Whether a man should avoid using a word that may to some extent be other-gender-identified is strictly situational, and the starting point for making that judgment is to ask, what are you afraid of, anyway? Along those lines, I wouldn't recommend using the term "sweetie pie" in a biker bar—whether the other patrons are male or female.

Comment: Why close? It's not entirely about opinion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, according to renowned linguist Robin Lakoff in her seminal book [Language and Woman's Place](http://www.stanford.edu/class/linguist156/Lakoff_1973.pdf) *lovely* is indeed a word that tends to be used more by women than by men:

> There is a group of adjectives which have, besides their specific and
>   literal  meanings, another use, that of indicating the speaker's
>   approbation or admiration  for something. Some of these adjectives are
>   neutral as to sex of speaker: either  men or women may use them. But
>   another set seems, in its figurative use, to be  largely confined to
>   women's speech. Representative lists of both types are below:
>
> *neutral*: great, terrific, cool, neat
>   *women only*: adorable, charming, sweet, **lovely**, divine

[On Gender-Related Differences in Daily Communication of English](http://www1.open.edu.cn/elt/27/23.htm) is a good overview of Lakoff's work and of more recent research.

Answer (score 4):

If this site (EL&U) is representative of the whole of English, then yes. Women do use it; I can't recall reading one example of a man using it. (Not that it hasn't been used; I just haven't seen it.) However, Benedict Cumberbatch swears **a lot** and still says [*lovely*](http://www.shortlist.com/entertainment/tv/benedict-cumberbatch).

Which I think is *lovely*, of course.

Comment: Well, I will tell you here and now how lovely I find the personalised artistic device that you use on this site. So - you have now heard a male person use the word. I don't actually believe that this can possibly be the first time. –

Comment: @Susan: Methinks the lady doth protest too much! To [recast a cliche](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22say+that+to+all+the+ladies%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), I bet all the gentlemen say that to you!

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I know the google-fu is strong in you; it seems the lady-fu is as well. ;)

Comment: @WS2 - same to you! ;)

Comment: @Susan: Steady on, old girl! (Or should that be: "Ooo-er missus!" :) Firstly, there's [this recent meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/) to consider, and secondly - ashamed as I am of thinking of this - there's [the coarse slang usage](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fufu&defid=1330549) which I've certainly heard in Wales, though that link says it's Australian.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - lol, fufu! I wish I had known that 24 years ago. I taught my first-born (son) the proper names for "privates". I was rewarded for my stupidity for weeks, as he would point to every adult in the grocery store asking **loudly**, "Mommy, does that man/woman have a p**** or a v*****?" How much less embarassing it would have been to hear something as benign as that!

Comment: I'm relieved you saw the funny side of that! Actually, we taught my (only) son to use p**** when he was little, but presumably because they weren't particularly relevant at the time, we never really bothered with tes****es*. He's over 25 now, but more than once in the past decade I've been (slightly) embarrassed on his behalf if, say, he catches a tennis ball in the nether regions. He automatically exclaims *"Argh! That got me right in the p***!". At his age, I think I'd rather hear [g**s](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goolie) or [n**s](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nuts).

Comment: *Lovely* is also used sarcastically; for example, if there is one more difficulty added to a problem; I suspect this use is predominantly male.